# Как удалить первую строку из двумерного массива путём смещения?

Tags: delphi, массивы

Подскажите, как удалить первую строку из двумерного массива, а затем "поднять" все остальные строки?

Answer (score 2):

циклом перебирайте, и смещайте.

пробуйте так:

```
var 
a:array[0..100,1..2] of integer;
i:integer;
begin
for i:=1 to 100 do
begin
a[i-1,1]:=a[i,1];
a[i-1,2]:=a[i,2];
end;
end;
```

Comment: а можно по конкретнее

Comment: Можно когда вы напишите какой у Вас массив. и что в последний элемент массива писать если первый удадлили

Comment: в последнюю строку добавлять ничего не надо, просто надо после того как удалили все элементы первой строки, поднять все остальные

Comment: ответ поправил добавил код.
Для массива [0..100,1..2]

Comment: неа чёт не работает, делал так:

procedure up( matr:matrix);
var
i,j,k:integer;
begin
for i := 1 to nmax do
for j := 1 to nmax do

  matr[i-1,j]:=matr[i,j];
end;

Comment: Во первых если вы передаете матрицу то и возвращайте её.
во вторых лучше использовать функцию а не процедуру.
в третьих тип matrix и nmax это что то специфическое.

Comment: в Вашем коде не стоит передавать матрицу, а объявить ее глобальной, а во вторых возможно **nmax** требует каких то аргументов.